# Symfony profiler extremely slow

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

When I started developing with Symfony on Windows it worked pretty well at first, but lately the profiler is taking way too long to load the toolbar.

[image: Profiler loading time]

The profiler is taking 18.48 seconds to load (day:116).

I didn't find anything helpful online, does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: If you have not already, you should take a look at [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: Are you using Docker?

Comment: No, I am not using Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is super weird, but after I did a JSON request (that returns a JsonResponse) everything turned back to normal. I have no idea why this had an effect at all, since this problem persisted over hours and server restarts did nothing. Anyway, I hope this might help someone else in the future.

**Edit:** The problem returned after a while, and there didn't seem to be any fix. I was using XAMPP on Windows 10 with Xdebug, APCu and OPcache. My hardware was definitely not the problem, I was running the server on a really beefy machine.

**Kind of fix for people with the same problem:**
I started using a Ubuntu VM, and it never happens there, even though I use the exact same code and server setup aside from the OS.